# Unable to find method 'com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm trying to setup an android project and I got the following error.

> Unable to find method
>   'com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's
>     dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network
>     connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync project
>     (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process
>     (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this
>     problem. Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
> - Your
>     project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with
>     the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by
>     the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can
>   also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue referring to below link

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/40035684/5735893][1]